# Problems migrating to PrimeFaces 12, Sapphire 5.1 and WildFly 28

Tags: jsf, primefaces, wildfly, jakarta-migration

I am migrating my Prime Faces application from version 7 to version 12, my Sapphire Template to version Sapphire 5.1 and my application server from WildFly 17 to WildFly 28.

As WildFly 28 does not support Java EE anymore (and hence all packages javax.*), I replaced everywhere in my source code my references to javax.* by jakarta.*
Since I am using Maven, this included also migrating my pom.xml as well.

I have the following problem: As far as I know, I must migrate javax.faces.* to jakarta.faces.*, but I am unable to do so in the primefaces 12.0.0 jar, which I am actually migrating to. There I have, for example:

```
package org.primefaces.model;

import javax.faces.component.UIComponent;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.model.ListDataModel;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.faces.convert.Converter;
import javax.faces.model.DataModelEvent;
import javax.faces.model.DataModelListener;


public abstract class LazyDataModel<T> extends ....
```

How can I solve that problem?

Comment: primefaces jars come in two flavours:  `Java EE` and `Jakarta`: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/primefaces/primefaces/12.0.0/. Just add `<classifier>jakarta</classifier>` to your dependency.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using maven, use the following dependency for Primefaces that supports Jakarta.

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
    <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
    <version>12.0.3</version>
    <classifier>jakarta</classifier>
</dependency>
```